# Assign the value of a dynamic element to another element

Tags: xaml

I have a ellipse with "width='auto'", and I want a circle, so it's not possible set "height='auto'" because if the user resize the window, the circle will be a ellipse. I've tried "Height='{Binding ElementName=TheLeft, Path=Width}'".

```
<Page
    x:Class="App2.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App2"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="White">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!--<Ellipse x:Name="TheLeft" Fill="Pink" Grid.Column="0" Height="{Binding ElementName=TheLeft, Path=Width}" Width="auto" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>-->
        <!-- I've set Height="200" in the uncommented element -->
        <Ellipse x:Name="TheLeft" Fill="Pink" Grid.Column="0" Height="200" Width="auto" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>

        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Grid.Column="1" RadiusX="50" RadiusY="40"/>
        <Ellipse Fill="Pink" Grid.Column="2" Height="200" Width="auto" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I am going to definitely suggest you take out the inline styling, especially since you want the same values for many of the properties for the two Ellipses.

```
<Style x:Key="circularEllipse" TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse"}>
   <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Pink"/>
   <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
   <Setter Property="Height" Value="200"/>
   <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding Path=Height, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
</Style>
```

And then when you code the ellipse - you just need to call this style and it can be used for both of them, saving you coding time and reducing the amount of code on your layout.

```
<Ellipse x:Name="TheLeft" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResouce circularEllipse}"/>
```

So, if you need to change the size of the circle, you only have to change the property in one place. Also, if you need a variant, you can use the BasedOn option and not have to redo the entire code. Such as:

```
<Style x:Key="circularEllipse2" TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}" BasedOn="{StaticResource circularEllipse}">
   <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
</Style>
```

This will pick up all of the other properties from the previous style, but change the height (or any other property you may need to change)